# How far is wearable device (android)

Tags: android, wear-os

It is possible to detect how far is a wear (android watch - moto360) from conected device (android phone)?

I need to detect how far is the device to esure the safety when you unlock the phone.

I researched API, but I don't found any way to detect far. Google describes only location detection over GPS, but no detection how far is device.

Thx

Comment: Have you done any research yourself?  Search the API, and indicate you have done some work before asking a question.

Comment: Yes, I researched API, but I don't found any way to detect far.

Google describes only location detection over GPS, but no detection how far is device.

Comment: I guess the only way would be to check if you detect your watch over Bluetooth or not, ie check if your devices are connected.